# tcl - how to save all parameters that go into a proc for later re-use?

Tags: parameters, tcl, procedure

I am using a function (A) that forms the content of a packet.
The function accepts an arbitrary amount of arguments.
I wish to implement another function (B) that forms that last packet formed by (A).
I wish to do this by running (A) on the same parameters I last used with (A).
The trick is (A) accepts an unknown number of parameters using something like

```
proc example {first {second ""} args}
```

Is there any easy way to save all the arguments quickly and then call (A) with the same params again at a later time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to have `A` create `B` when run, which it's pretty simple to do with the help of `info level 0`:

```
proc A {p q {r ...} args} {
    # Make B which will call us *exactly* as we've just been called
    proc B {} [list uplevel 1 [info level 0]]
    # ... continue with normal processing ...
}
```

There are certain caveats to this (e.g., if you're doing heavy processing with aliases or complex cross-namespace work) but for most code — especially the sort of thing where you'd want this — that's not a big deal.

---

<sup>In 8.6, use `proc B {} [list tailcall {*}[info level 0]]` instead.</sup>

Comment: One of the params I give A is the name of a (IN OUT) variable I want to get back later.. How do I grab that value?
Can I just call proc B from anywhere later? do I need to assign it to a global scope somehow..

Comment: @Arthur: It really depends on what you mean by that. It will still be passed as an argument with exactly the same name; invoke it _in the same context_ and it will behave identically. Invoke it somewhere else… well, if that causes problems, `A` is not a great candidate for this sort of thing IMO.

Comment: @Arthur: If you were going to allow replacement of the variable names being passed in, you'd have to write a much more complicated `B` to do it (since it has to process its arguments and understand what to replace and how). Yes, you can, but it starts to become easier _as well as clearer_ to just cut-n-paste the original invocation of `A` instead.

Comment: I don't know about other aspects but your answer is wonderful! for what the question specifies and I expect others who look for an answer would appreciate how good this is.. so I'm just going to keep it as the correct answer

Comment: I wanted to thank you again. I'm not sure what were the limitations you described that could occur potentially in more complex use cases. In the current case, this worked wonderfully and helped me well.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could use a global array to store the parameters:

```
proc printArguments {first {second ""} args} {
global params
set params(first) $first
set params(second) $second
set params(args) $args
}
%
%
% printArguments 1 2 3 4 5
3 4 5
%
% parray params
params(args)   = 3 4 5
params(first)  = 1
params(second) = 2
```

Comment: How do I run the proc again on these arguments? Thanks

Comment: The other answer is miles better than mine!

Comment: I realised after playing with my code a bit that a list is much better to use in this case than the array. And of course, using "info args" is much nicer than hardcoding the parameters